# Android Image Library for beauty filters, removing red eyes, crop etc

Tags: android, image, image-processing, imagefilter

I'm trying to find the Android library which allows (primary) to apply beauty filters to images, add blur for background, remove red eyes, etc. + standard features like cropping, etc. For cropping, for example - I found a solution, but for filters, blur, removing red eyes, it's almost impossible.

Can you suggest any libraries for that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below libraries -

1 - [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

2 - [PhotoFiltersSDK](https://mindorks.com/android/store/Image-Processing/zomato/androidphotofilters)

3 - [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/)

Features they provide -

- ToneCurveSubfilter : With this powerful filter you can change RGB
  channels of any image to create great results.
- SaturationSubfitler : Used for changing color saturation of an image.
  ColorOverlaySubfilter : As name suggests you can overlay any image
  with color of your choice.
- ContrastSubfilter : Used for changing contrast value of image.
- BrightnessSubfilter : To change brightness levels.
- VignetteSubfilter : To apply vignette effect on image.

and many more..